# Turn Char into KeyEvent

Tags: java, awtrobot

I am making a little program for educational reasons (Have no practical usage really :P).

What I am trying to accomplish, is feeding a Text to a Robot and then make it open up Notepad and type out the text using KeyPress and KeyRelease. I know probably not nice to the JVM in general ;P

My problem is, that I have trouble finding a general solution to turning a Character I read from the document, into the appropriate KeyEvent. I've looked around the net and haven't really found a solution. Or at least not one that's seems either overly complex or just look like grunt work.

So my question is, would this be possible to accomplish by using the Java Library or do I have to make up the logic myself? I hope this question suits Stackoverflow.

Comment: I think that yes, this is possible using the core Java libary, and yes, you'll likely have to do the grunt work yourself.

Comment: Ah well, since no one answered I already began constructing a HashMap of Characters and corresponding KeyEvent codes. Thanks though! After looking through a few solutions, it seems to be the..least complex to execute.